# Google Form API

Tags: java, google-forms-api

I am creating a Google Form using the Google Forms API. Is there a way to set an expiration for the form or disable the responses after a certain period of time?

I am using Java.

I tried to find if there is something that is given in the documentation but found nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.